# Cannot coerce class typeOf is double to a data.frame

Tags: r, statistics

I want to convert the output from my `pcomp()` function to a data frame the problem is that using:

When using `as.data.frame` I get:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data.pca1$loadings) : 
  cannot coerce class ""loadings"" to a data.frame
```

My problem is that I do not know another way to convert the data to a `dataframe`.

My data:

```
dput(data.pca1$loading)
structure(c(0.629999587107591, 0.544821342951502, 0.757214347947699, 
0.140799724239407, 0.195350889504226, 0.30782155605534, 0.113779470611058, 
0.25319481053313, 0.530575304369119, 0.161372414349993, 0.172071942829558, 
0.181110279027528, 0.32087938033537, 0.199923250086931, 0.112976439383677, 
0.435960093914842, 0.735714667273012, 0.546839296993964, 0.618721696774699, 
0.157746933602662, 0.196394937008026, 0.323352336171706, 0.312677801641149, 
0.0540081734469586, 0.236882360216423, 0.160496430572191, 0.126509131465792, 
0.160239501804437, 0.28141267308665, 0.286102918406781, 0.59838483667591, 
0.588492755323989, 0.597607970656895, -0.00300183993888212, 0.132863946525179, 
0.3091527351007, 0.967808869898446, 0.460034358552482, 0.0613549566320599, 
0.0823819988685729, 0.243877077120173, 0.0998230648040528, 0.0718231415302767, 
0.241248015517299), .Dim = c(11L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Q1", 
"Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12"
), c("Factor1", "Factor2", "Factor3", "Factor4")), class = "loadings")
```

I really appreciate any idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution can be simple.

```
as.data.frame(unclass(data.pca1$loadings))
```

The explanation is also simple. Object of class loadings cannot be converted to data.frame by default. Thus you can remove class of the object with `unclass` statement and it was implicilty coerced to matrix, which you may convert to data.frame.

Comment: You should accompany your solution with an explanation on how each part works.

Comment: The code is so self-explaining for me that it was difficult to comment it, but I added some explanations.